# How to fill missing faces in three js?

Tags: three.js, fbx

I have a ground object (.fbx). but when i load it, some faces are missing! But no holes like that in actual model. How to fix it through three js while rendering?[image]

Comment: As a work-around, try `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;` -- but it would be nice to understand why that is happening.

Comment: @WestLangley I already tried this! No use!

Comment: Then you need to identify where the bug is occuring -- in the .fbx file, or in `FBXLoader`.

Comment: Could also be a corrupted export.

Comment: No problem in model, coz when i import it in 3ds max, it looks fine!